# How to delete the last column in a CSV file?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I want to remove the last text words from these data. How can I do it in Python?

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.0,1.4,0.1,Iris-setosa
4.3,3.0,1.1,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.8,4.0,1.2,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.7,4.4,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.3,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.7,3.8,1.7,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.8,1.5,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.4,1.7,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.7,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.6,1.0,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.9,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.0,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.6,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.2,3.5,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.2,3.4,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.1,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.4,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.2,4.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.5,4.2,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.2,1.2,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.5,3.5,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
4.4,3.0,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.5,1.3,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.5,2.3,1.3,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.4,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.5,1.6,0.6,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.8,1.9,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.0,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.8,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.3,4.0,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.5,2.8,4.6,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.8,4.5,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.3,3.3,4.7,1.6,Iris-versicolor
4.9,2.4,3.3,1.0,Iris-versicolor
6.6,2.9,4.6,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.2,2.7,3.9,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5.0,2.0,3.5,1.0,Iris-versicolor
5.9,3.0,4.2,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.0,2.2,4.0,1.0,Iris-versicolor
6.1,2.9,4.7,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5.6,2.9,3.6,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.7,3.1,4.4,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5.6,3.0,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.8,2.7,4.1,1.0,Iris-versicolor
6.2,2.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.6,2.5,3.9,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.9,3.2,4.8,1.8,Iris-versicolor
6.1,2.8,4.0,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.3,2.5,4.9,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.1,2.8,4.7,1.2,Iris-versicolor
6.4,2.9,4.3,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.6,3.0,4.4,1.4,Iris-versicolor
6.8,2.8,4.8,1.4,Iris-versicolor
6.7,3.0,5.0,1.7,Iris-versicolor
6.0,2.9,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.6,3.5,1.0,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.8,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.4,3.7,1.0,Iris-versicolor
5.8,2.7,3.9,1.2,Iris-versicolor
6.0,2.7,5.1,1.6,Iris-versicolor
5.4,3.0,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.0,3.4,4.5,1.6,Iris-versicolor
6.7,3.1,4.7,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.3,2.3,4.4,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.6,3.0,4.1,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.5,4.0,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.5,2.6,4.4,1.2,Iris-versicolor
6.1,3.0,4.6,1.4,Iris-versicolor
5.8,2.6,4.0,1.2,Iris-versicolor
5.0,2.3,3.3,1.0,Iris-versicolor
5.6,2.7,4.2,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.7,3.0,4.2,1.2,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.9,4.2,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.2,2.9,4.3,1.3,Iris-versicolor
5.1,2.5,3.0,1.1,Iris-versicolor
5.7,2.8,4.1,1.3,Iris-versicolor
6.3,3.3,6.0,2.5,Iris-virginica
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,Iris-virginica
7.1,3.0,5.9,2.1,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.9,5.6,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.5,3.0,5.8,2.2,Iris-virginica
7.6,3.0,6.6,2.1,Iris-virginica
4.9,2.5,4.5,1.7,Iris-virginica
7.3,2.9,6.3,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.7,2.5,5.8,1.8,Iris-virginica
7.2,3.6,6.1,2.5,Iris-virginica
6.5,3.2,5.1,2.0,Iris-virginica
6.4,2.7,5.3,1.9,Iris-virginica
6.8,3.0,5.5,2.1,Iris-virginica
5.7,2.5,5.0,2.0,Iris-virginica
5.8,2.8,5.1,2.4,Iris-virginica
6.4,3.2,5.3,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.5,3.0,5.5,1.8,Iris-virginica
7.7,3.8,6.7,2.2,Iris-virginica
7.7,2.6,6.9,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.0,2.2,5.0,1.5,Iris-virginica
6.9,3.2,5.7,2.3,Iris-virginica
5.6,2.8,4.9,2.0,Iris-virginica
7.7,2.8,6.7,2.0,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.7,4.9,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.3,5.7,2.1,Iris-virginica
7.2,3.2,6.0,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.2,2.8,4.8,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.1,3.0,4.9,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.4,2.8,5.6,2.1,Iris-virginica
7.2,3.0,5.8,1.6,Iris-virginica
7.4,2.8,6.1,1.9,Iris-virginica
7.9,3.8,6.4,2.0,Iris-virginica
6.4,2.8,5.6,2.2,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.8,5.1,1.5,Iris-virginica
6.1,2.6,5.6,1.4,Iris-virginica
7.7,3.0,6.1,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.3,3.4,5.6,2.4,Iris-virginica
6.4,3.1,5.5,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.0,3.0,4.8,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.9,3.1,5.4,2.1,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.1,5.6,2.4,Iris-virginica
6.9,3.1,5.1,2.3,Iris-virginica
5.8,2.7,5.1,1.9,Iris-virginica
6.8,3.2,5.9,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.3,5.7,2.5,Iris-virginica
6.7,3.0,5.2,2.3,Iris-virginica
6.3,2.5,5.0,1.9,Iris-virginica
6.5,3.0,5.2,2.0,Iris-virginica
6.2,3.4,5.4,2.3,Iris-virginica
5.9,3.0,5.1,1.8,Iris-virginica
```

Comment: Which ones dear!?

Comment: "iris-setosa", "iris-virginica" all the letter words.i want to print only the integer values

Comment: It's csv file, comma separated file, are you familiar with pandas?

Comment: @Media Do we have a meta post for all/some of the common questions which keeps on popping? (Like having a FAQ tag)

Comment: @Media Something equivalent to this for Data Science Platform too https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions

Comment: @Aditya Actually I don't think so. But I have a suggestion. I think our community is so young, even our field is so young. I admire people who try to learn and find answers of their question. Humiliating is not an academic behaviour that unfortunately we see that on some among StackOverflow's users. I welcome our new users which are not familiar with the field entirely and ask questions which have same equivalents on the community but not an exact solution. I guess helping people which are not very familiar to the field is very accesptable, I believe in helping everybody I can help :)

Comment: I too don't want to humiliate the way I was humiliated, this SE is much better, had it been like SO this question would have easily fetched atleast 10+ downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know pandas? If you don't know it yet, install it through "pip" by typing "pip install pandas" or through your conda environment.

Then, in your code or jupyter notebook, read the csv file:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("iris.csv")
```

After that you only need to remove the last column:

```
df.drop(df.columns[len(df.columns)-1], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Now your variable df has only the numerical columns you want.

Comment: no i am not familiar with pandas.i m doing this in pycharm.i m new to python

Comment: Start [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html) then.

Comment: That's the target variable, use Label Encoder to convert or One Hot, We can't simply drop , isn't?

Comment: @Aditya his request was to drop it. If it was to build a proper classifier, it would be a viable option to use Label Encoder.